# How extract specific number pattern from a list inside column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data frame like below to which I need to following transformations

1. Extract and keep only 3 decimals from first number before `comma ,` and  also keep only  3 decimal points for second number .
2. Comma should replaced by `:`
3. If the number has only two decimal points and add one zero extra to make it 3 decimal points.

**Input**

```
  df
    [151.20732,-33.86785]
    [81.67732,-09.86]
    [1.2890,43.8] 
    [567.200,33.867]
    [557.21,33.86]
```

**Expected Output**

```
151.207:-33.867
81.677:-09.860
1.289:43.800
567.200:33.867
557.210,33.860
```

How can this be done in pandas?

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to create your dataframe? I have never seen a dataframe with that format.

Comment: @Jakub, I uploaded sample dataset here :https://www.dropbox.com/s/58gqdp2pf0ukfvt/Test_data.csv?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how my code differed from @YOBEN_S's code. You said you got an error from my code, so I provided the code I used to create the df. I got a similar error when attempting to run YOBEN_S's code. Since his code worked for you, I was wanting to see how you defined your df.

Comment: @Jakub, you need to make small change @YOBEN_S code `((int(y * 10 ** n)) / 10 ** n)` which keeps -ve numbers as such

Answer (score 3):

This is hard than I thought

```
def func(y,n):
    if y < 0 :
      return "%0.3f" % (-(y * 10 ** n // -1 / 10 ** n))
    else :
      return "%0.3f" % (y * 10 ** n // 1 / 10 ** n)
    

df.apply(lambda x : ':'.join([ func (y, 3) for y in x]) )
Out[86]: 
0    151.207:33.867
1      81.677:9.860
2      1.289:43.800
3    567.200:33.867
4    557.210:33.860
dtype: object
```

Input

```
data = [[151.20732,-33.86785],
        [81.67732,-09.86],
        [1.2890,43.8],
        [567.200,33.867],
        [557.21,33.86]]
df = pd.Series(data)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219375/discussion-on-answer-by-yoben-s-how-extract-specific-number-pattern-from-a-list).

Answer (score 0):

**DataFrame Input Option 1:**

```
data = [[[151.20732,-33.86785]],
        [[81.67732,-09.86]],
        [[1.2890,43.8]],
        [[567.200,33.867]],
        [[557.21,33.86]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['geo'])
```

**DataFrame Input Option 2:**
*literal_eval is used to read a CSV file that contains a list, otherwise list is read as a single string.*

```
import ast

literal = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
data = pd.read_csv('/Test_data.csv', converters={'geo.geometry.coordinates': literal})

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['geo.geometry.coordinates'])
df.rename(columns = {'geo.geometry.coordinates':'geo'}, inplace = True)
```

**Algorithm:**

```
import math

def trunc(f,d):
    # Truncate float (f) to d decimal places, unless NaN
    return 'nan' if math.isnan(f) else f"{int(f*10**d)/10**d:0.{d}f}"

df['geo_neo'] = df.apply(lambda r:  trunc(r['geo'][0], 3) + ':'
                                  + trunc(r['geo'][1], 3), axis = 1)
```

**DataFrame Output:**

```
                      geo          geo_neo
0  [151.20732, -33.86785]  151.207:-33.867
1       [81.67732, -9.86]    81.677:-9.860
2           [1.289, 43.8]     1.289:43.800
3         [567.2, 33.867]   567.200:33.867
4         [557.21, 33.86]   557.210:33.860
```

Comment: getting error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @aeapen Maybe our dataframes were defined different. I added the dataframe I used.

Comment: @aeapen Did you want the decimals truncated or rounded? You can have them truncated by simply removing the round function from my code.

Comment: I want them to truncated, if it is less than two or less decimals point add additional zero to make them 3 decimals

Comment: @aeapen I'm confused. You wanted to turn all the negative numbers to positive numbers in your output? The answer you selected has all positive numbers. That's different than the expect output you gave in your question.

Comment: I dont want to turn negative to positive numbers. Keep the numbers in respective forms

Comment: aeapen, the answer you selected by @YOBEN_S gives all positives numbers.

Comment: Somehow, your code doesnt work when I apply it on my dateset.  I have uploaded  sample data in questions. can you try with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219309/discussion-between-jakub-and-aeapen).